# Basis vector as "Array" choice in tensor calculus / GR, and 3+1 decomposition

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, adm-formalism

In differential geometry and general relativity, once we have chosen a basis on our spacetime, say $ \{t,r,\theta, \phi \} $, we can represent every tensor as an "array" of numbers, so a "vector" for (1,0) and (0,1) tensors, a "matrix" for (2,0), (1,1) and (0,2) tensors, and so on..

The $\mu$-th basis vectors on our tangent space can be written as $$(\partial_{\mu})^a$$
While that of our cotangent space as $$ (dx^{\mu})_a $$ where $d$ is the exterior derivative.

When doing explicit calculations, we have to represent our basis as an "array" (vector), but I'm not entirely sure which one should be the trivial, ie. $\delta_{\mu}^a$ or $\delta_{a}^{\mu}$. Both clearly cannot, since the metric provides a natural isomorphism between them, so once one has been chosen, the other can be calculated as well.

Basically, I don't know whether
$$\begin{align}
     (\partial_{t})^a&= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$$
or $$\begin{align}
     (dx^{t})_a&= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$$
Up until recently I was using the first one, and getting good results, but having read some papers that use the latter I got confused.

In classic 3+1 or ADM decomposition [1] [2], we have a global time function $t$, the level surfaces of which are 3 dimensional spacelike hypersurfaces. We then choose an "evolution vector field" $t^a$ (disregard the abuse of notation), such that
$$t^a \nabla_a(t)=1$$

Using this we can find the unit norm timelike vector field $n^a$ as
$$n^a=\frac{1}{\alpha} \cdot [(\partial_{t})^a - \beta^a]$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta^a$ are the lapse function and shift vector respectively, and $(\partial_{t})^a \equiv t^a$ is the evolution vector field, which (I think) we can choose as (1,0,0,0). The unit normal (co)vector can be also written as
$$ n_a \equiv g_{a,b} n^b = (dx^{t})_a \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g^{a,b}(dx^{t})_a (dx^{t})_b }} $$

My question is, first of all, which of the above basis is usually chosen, why, and whether it even matters. I'm hesitant to believe in the second choice, because this makes the $\alpha$ lapse negative, something that is usually regarded as very bad.

References:

[1] Rácz (2014) Is the Bianchi identity always hyperbolic? https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1016

[2] Rácz (2014) Cauchy problem as a two-surface based 'geometrodynamics'
,  Class. Quantum Grav. 32 015006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I find your notation a bit confusing, but I will try to cope with it. The given problem deals with vector fields $X$ and one-forms $\omega$. We adapt here the differential-geometric approach. We will decompose $X$ and $\omega$ is its components (a=0,1,2,3 and these 4 coordinates are not necessarily cartesian, for instance $\partial_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is possible. But actually they could be even anholonomic):

$$ X = x^a \partial_a \quad \quad \text{and}\quad\quad \omega = \omega_a dx^a.$$

In case one has a vector field that points along time-coordinate $t$ it would simply be $X =\partial_t$. Or if it is expressed in its components  one would have

$$X = (\partial_t)^a \partial_a  = \partial_t $$

Therefore the values of $(\partial_t)^a$ are

$$ (\partial_t)^a = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

One-forms, on the other hand, are in the dual space of vector fields.
The base vectors fulfill the following  property:

$$dx^a(\partial_b) = \delta^a_b$$

The dual vector, actually better called co-vector,  of the $\partial_t$ would be dt. If one considers such a co-vector one would express it in components like this:
$$ \omega = (dx^t)_a dx^a =dt \quad \quad \text{or better} \quad\quad \omega= \omega_a dx^a =dt$$

Actually I am not used to the notation of the very left side  and instead I would prefer to write it like $\omega = \omega_a dx^a$

Therefore the values of $\omega_a$ are (choosing a row vector to express the duality to $(\partial_t)^a$)

$$ \omega_a = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$

or even more elementary: $\omega_0 = 1$ and $\omega_{1,2,3} = 0$. You can replace $\omega_a $ by $(dx^t)_a$ if you like.

Then the equations in the lower part of the post make sense (at least formally, actually I am not an expert of the physics described by them).
There one only deals with the components of vector fields $X$ or one-forms $\omega$.

In particular the components of $\partial_t$ and $dt$ are dual each other which --- once  the components of the the differential objects $X$ and $\omega$ mapped in linear-algebraic vector space --- end up as column or row vectors. Of course one is free to make the choice vice-versa, i.e. map components of vector field to a row and map components of an one-form to a column.